# Display a custom single.twig for specific categories

Tags: wordpress, twig, timber

In timber you can display custom pages, based on page.twig, like page-casestudies.twig, which I'm using to show a list of all posts with a category of 'casestudies'.  Just including /casestudies in the URL will render the page.  This is default timber functionality and works exactly as I'd expect.  I then want to show (for casestudies) a custom single-casestudies.twig, which is based off but different to single.twig (which I use for blog posts) and needs a different layout.  I use additional ACF's in the casestudies.  I have no idea how I go about this, or if it is even possible, or if there is a better way, such as custom post types.  I've seen lots of posts about custom post types, but they only mention a list of posts, and not the actual display of the custom post itself.  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think Timber has this functionality by default, but you could add it yourself to `single.php` like this:

```
$context = Timber::get_context();
$context['post'] = new Timber\Post();
$template = has_category('casestudies') ? 'single-casestudies.twig' : 'single.twig';

Timber::render($template, $context);
```

The `$template` variable checks if the post contains the category `casestudies`, and sets the template to either `single-casestudies.twig` or `single.twig`.

Comment: Hi Daniel.  That's great, works perfectly, much appreciated.  If I wanted to add a second category what's the syntax for that?  If I repeat the third line and replace 'casestudies' with 'news' that works fine but then case studies no longer works and falls back to the defauly single.twig.

Comment: Hi Daniel, in the end I was able to achieve this using if, elseif and else.  Thanks again for your help.

Comment: @doifeellucky Your solution will work fine. Just keep in mind that the order of the if statements will determine which template is used (because a post can have both 'casestudies' and 'news' as categories). Don't forget to mark your question as answered if everything is clear :)

Comment: I did think about the fact that they might use multiple categories.  Is there a better way expanding on your original solution?  I'd expect there to be multiple categories like case studies, news, blog, etc. Thanks.